# company mode: seamless scrolling for completion suggestions

Tags: company-mode

How do I enable seamless scrolling for company-mode suggestions?

To wit, I'd like to return to the top suggestion if I scroll down from the last, and go the the bottom if I scroll up from the first.

I've tried to look this up, but I'm uncertain whether 1) this has never been asked before or 2) I don't have the right keyword to search for.

Comment: Does `(setq company-selection-wrap-around t)` not meet your requirements? The docstring says "If enabled, selecting item before first or after last wraps around."

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks!